# Jquery + HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have an html table: the top row consists of `<td>`s that are buttons:

```
<td onmouseover="tokenColor(this)" onmouseout="noToken(this)" onclick="dropToken(this, 1)"></td>
```

When clicked, the function calls `dropToken()` to change the color of the `<td>` and drop a "token" to the the matching column on the last row (connect four) by changing its `background-color` to `playerTurn` which is a variable that defines the players turn and the token color. However the jquery section in `dropToken()` does not work and stops the rest of the function from continuing.

```
function dropToken(obj, column)
        {
            $('table tr:last-child td:nth-child(column)').css("background-color", playerTurn);
            if (playerTurn == "Red")
            {
                playerTurn = "Blue"
                obj.style.backgroundColor = "Blue";   
            }
            else
            {
                playerTurn = "Red"
                obj.style.backgroundColor = "Red"; 
            }
        }
```

Please help! Thanks

```
        <script>
        var playerTurn = "Red"
        var column = 0;

        function tokenColor (obj) 
        {
            if (playerTurn == "Red")
            {
                obj.style.background = "Red";
                obj.style.border = "2px solid black";
            }
            else
            {
                obj.style.backgroundColor = "Blue";
                obj.style.border = "2px solid black";
            }
        }

        function noToken(obj)
        {
            obj.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            obj.style.border = "2px solid white";
        }

        function dropToken(obj, column)
        {
            $('table tr:last-child td:nth-child(' + column + ')').css("background-color", playerTurn);
            if (playerTurn == "Red")
            {
                playerTurn = "Blue"
                obj.style.backgroundColor = "Blue";   
            }
            else
            {
                playerTurn = "Red"
                obj.style.backgroundColor = "Red"; 
            }
        }

        function resetBoard()
        {
            location.reload()
        }
    </script>

    <h1>Connect Four</h1>
    <table>
        <tr class="topRow">
            <td onmouseover="tokenColor(this)" onmouseout="noToken(this)" onclick="dropToken(this, 1)"></td>
            <td onmouseover="tokenColor(this)" onmouseout="noToken(this)" onclick="dropToken(this, 2)"></td>
            <td onmouseover="tokenColor(this)" onmouseout="noToken(this)" onclick="dropToken(this, 3)"></td>
            <td onmouseover="tokenColor(this)" onmouseout="noToken(this)" onclick="dropToken(this, 4)"></td>
            <td onmouseover="tokenColor(this)" onmouseout="noToken(this)" onclick="dropToken(this, 5)"</td>
            <td onmouseover="tokenColor(this)" onmouseout="noToken(this)" onclick="dropToken(this, 6)"></td>
            <td onmouseover="tokenColor(this)" onmouseout="noToken(this)" onclick="dropToken(this, 7)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="resetBoard()">Empty Tokens</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Any JS console errors?

Comment: type `$('table tr:last-child td:nth-child(column)')` into your js console and see if it returns an element, if it doesn't it's an issue with your selector query.

Comment: Where is the associated html? WIthout that it is very hard to replicate your issues

Comment: @charlietfl i just added it

Comment: Potentially a dumb question: Have you included the jQuery library? I ask because your code seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/mgje9zye/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this `$('table tr:last-child td:nth-child(column)')` to this  `$('table tr:last-child td:nth-child(' + column + ')')`

Comment: I tried changing this but it didn't seem to fix the problem?

Comment: @JoshKonowitz then we will need your html and more code maybe? :)

Comment: @JoshK I see that it worked! what was the last problem you were struggling?

Comment: I forgot to insert the jquery library as @Jon P said in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with some refactoring while you are at it and keep it consistent jQuery all the way through

```
function dropToken(obj, column)
{
   $('table tr:last-child td:nth-child(' + column + ')').css("background-color", playerTurn);

   //Toggle player turn value
   playerTurn = playerTurn == "Red" ? "Blue" : "Red";
   $(obj).css("background-color", playerTurn);
}
```

Simplifying even further with CSS and Jquery:

```js
$(".topRow td").click(function(){
    var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    
    
    var activePlayer = $(this).closest("table").data("activeplayer");
    $('table tr:last-child td:nth-child(' + (col + 1) + ')').css("background-color", activePlayer);

    
    //Toggle Active Player 
    activePlayer = activePlayer == "Red" ? "Blue" : "Red";
    $(this).closest("table").data("activeplayer", activePlayer);
    $(this).css("background-color", activePlayer);
});
```

```css
table[data-activePlayer="Blue"] .topRow td:hover
{
background-color:blue;    
}


.topRow td:hover
{
  border: 2px solid black;  
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table data-activeplayer="Red">
        <tr class="topRow">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```